# 2d Texture missing triangle chunk using SOIL and OpenGL (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, rendering, soil

I have some Java game dev experience and this is my first attempt at some C++ game dev.

This game is supposed to be a very simple 2d Game a sort of whack'a'mole but with bubbles.

It seems as though I'm not rendering my Sprites correctly so this happens:

How the texture should look like
[image: How the texture should look like]

Texture after rendering
[image: Texture after rendering]

I read [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads) so I resized my texture to 400x400px but that didn't fix anything.

Does this have to do with the depth? or with blending? what am I doing wrong?

---

Main:

```
#include "Engine\Engine.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Engine/Graphics/Sprite.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Engine engine;

    engine.Initialize("Bursting!");

    Sprite testSprite = Sprite("Assets/Art/Bubble.png", 100,100);

    while (true)
    {
        engine.Update();
        testSprite.Update();

        engine.BeginRender();
        testSprite.Render();
        engine.EndRender();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Engine.cpp:

```
#include "Engine.h"

int Engine::SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024;
int Engine::SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768;
GLFWwindow* Engine::window = NULL;

Engine::Engine()
{

}

Engine::~Engine()
{

}

bool Engine::Initialize(char* windowTitle)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "Error initializing GLFW" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, windowTitle, NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error creating window " << endl;
        return false;
    }

    //OpenGL Setup
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    int xPos = (mode->width - SCREEN_WIDTH) / 2;
    int xyPos = (mode->height - SCREEN_HEIGHT) / 2;

    //GL Setup
    //Viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -32, 32);
    glDepthRange(-32, 32);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    //Alpha Blending
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    return true;
}

void Engine::Update()
{
    glfwPollEvents(); 
}

void Engine::BeginRender()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); //clear back buffer 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

//this swaps buffers, anything that needs to be drawn and seen by human eyes needs to happen before this func
void Engine::EndRender()
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
}
```

---

Texture.cpp:

```
#include "Texture.h"

Texture::Texture()
{
    id = -1; //Opengl tracks our texture as, this allows us to set texture before drawing
}

Texture::Texture(int _id)
{
    id = _id;
    if (!GetTextureParams())
    {
        cout << "Error loading Image with ID: " << id << endl;
    }
}

Texture::Texture(string path)
{
    id = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(path.c_str(), SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA);
    if (!GetTextureParams()) 
    {
        cout << "Error loading Image from path: " << path << endl;
    }
}

int Texture::getId()
{
    return id;
}

int Texture::getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

int Texture::getHeight()
{
    return height;
}


bool Texture::GetTextureParams()
{
    if (id > 0)
    {
        int mipLevel = 0;
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
        glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mipLevel, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &width);
        glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mipLevel, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &height);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Sprite.cpp:

```
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite()
{
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0,

    texture = Texture();
}

Sprite::Sprite(string imgPath)
{
    texture = Texture(imgPath);
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0;

}

Sprite::Sprite(string imgPath, float _xPos, float _yPos)
{
    texture = Texture(imgPath);
    xPos = _xPos;
    yPos = _yPos;

}

void Sprite::Update()
{

}

void Sprite::Render()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D),
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getId());
    glLoadIdentity();

    //TRANS -> ROT -> SCALE
    glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, 0);


    //rendering
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);     glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);     glVertex2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);     glVertex2f(0 , texture.getHeight());
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);     glVertex2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was building it wrong or importing it wrong. i.e. Lines were in the wrong order:

in my sprite.cpp my render() looked like:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);     glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);     glVertex2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);     glVertex2f(0 , texture.getHeight()); //error    
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);     glVertex2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());

glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I changed the order :

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);     glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);     glVertex2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);     glVertex2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);     glVertex2f(0 , texture.getHeight()); //correct position

glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And it works now! Thanks.